# prohibited: getting knowledge from GoogleEarth photos/videos, and use it for own map?

Tags: google-earth, copyright

Is it prohibited to use knowledge you get from proprietary images or videos?
Example: I found a geotagged photo (ponramio) in Google Earth with a well on it. So I know: "Ah, there is a well where I can get water!". Can I use that knowledge to mark that well on my map? ...

Comment: Have you considered asking Google directly?

Comment: It is a very grey area, but if you found that well in Bing Maps Satellite and added that to OpenStreetMap that is okay as they have an agreement in place. see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bing#Announcement_and_licence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no lawyer, but unless your usage of the information falls under [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) (the definition of which varies by country), you need to get permission from the copyright holder. The [Panoramio TOS](http://www.panoramio.com/terms/) (Terms of Service) redirects to the [Google TOS](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/), which state:

> Using our Services does not give you ownership of any intellectual
>   property rights in our Services or the content you access. You may not
>   use content from our Services unless you obtain permission from its
>   owner or are otherwise permitted by law.

Additionally the Panoramio help [section on copyright](http://www.panoramio.com/help/copyright) has the following information:

> To use, copy, print, or download a photo from Panoramio, you must get
>   explicit permission from the photographer.

and

> You can not use the photos for any commercial or business purpose
>   other than with the explicit permission of the photographer.